# how to get last SelectedItem index from listview after refreshing in viewmodel using mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I can't access listview's selecteditem in viewmodel and i bound it to my CurrentProduct. How should i write the code in viewmodel so i can get the index of the CurrentProduct(selecteditem) so i after i refresh the listview  i can restore the value

**XAML**

```
<ListView Name="sItem"  BorderThickness="0.4" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentProduct}"/>
```

**VIEWMODEL** - this is how i refresh the listview

```
ProductList = ProductCollection.GetAllProducts();
```

my viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I think binding might be lost or you need to raise `PropertyChanged` after setting the list. Alternatively, make it a full property and set the private field as the list. You will need to then raise the property changed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a property on the ViewModel, e.g.:

```
private Product _productListSelectedItem;
public Product ProductListSelectedItem
{
    get { return _productListSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_productListSelectedItem != value)
        {
            _productListSelectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And then bind to this in your XAML:

```
<ListView Name="sItem" ... SelectedItem="{Binding ProductListSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When it comes to refreshing the `ListView`:

```
private void RefreshProductList()
{
    Product selectedItem = ProductListSelectedItem;

    ProductList = ProductCollection.GetAllProducts();

    if (ProductList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == selectedItem.ID) != null)
    {
        ProductListSelectedItem = ProductList.First(p => p.ID == selectedItem.ID);
    }
}
```

Once you've refreshed the `ProductList`, you'll have a new set of items, so what I've done here is to store the selected item before the collection changes, and then use a `LINQ` expression to locate that item in the new collection via a property called `ID`. I'm assuming you have a property or set of properties to locate distinct items, as I think you'll need one in this case.

(I've also assumed your individual class name as `Product`.)

Comment: i think you meant to say `Product selectedItem = ProductListSelectedItem`

Comment: You're welcome! - And correct, I've changed that property name. :)